# Using <DataTestMethod>, <DataRow....> with vb.net . Only one <DataRow> gets executed

Tags: vb.net, tdd, mstest

I'm trying to set up an automated unit test using MSTest. I have single tests working, and am now trying to set up parameterised tests using < DataTestMethod> and < DataRow(...)>. I'm following the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-visual-basic-with-mstest)

When I debug the test sequence below, the ParseTestData( ) is only called once, with the first  <DataRow ..> parameter. It is not called a second time.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

(Note: I found some articles indicating DataTestMethod is obsolete, and TestMethod works just the same. I tried  and got identical results)

[edit] - from @Mark Seemann 's suggestion, I've simplified this from the original post. Same problem.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Namespace TestDecoder.Tests
    <TestClass>
    Public Class DecoderTests
        Private DecoderInstance
        <DataTestMethod>
        <DataRow(New Byte() {&H41})>
        <DataRow(New Byte() {&H42})>
        Public Sub ParseTestData(Frame() As Byte)
            Dim result As Boolean
            DecoderInstance = New Decoder()
            result = DecoderInstance.parse(Frame(0))
            Assert.IsTrue(result, "Failed the dummy test")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I'm not sure if this will provide any more insight, but here is the Decoder code (Edited for Brevity).

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Public Class Decoder
    Function parse(rxchar As Byte) As Boolean
        Return rxchar = &H41
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: We don't know what `Decoder` is. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Edited - I'm not sure that this will help. I assumed the problem was in the Test code, as the ParseTestData() method is only being called once with the first DataRow.

Comment: That's not a bad assumption. Have you tried making the problem *smaller* in order to reproduce it?

Comment: Well actually this is the problem made smaller, but good idea. Working on it.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. I don't think this is a VB issue, since I can also reproduce it in C#, with both byte arrays and int arrays. Curious. I'm not an MSTest expert, so I'm drawing a blank, but I'll ask around.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSeemann - I've got a work around going for now, I store the test arrays in the test class, and use the < DataRow > to select which test array to run.

Comment: I've now reported this as a bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/DataRow-with-byte-array-doesnt-work-in/10222695