# How to initialise a jagged array of bytes as a class member

Tags: arrays, vb.net, mstest

I'm trying to find an alternative way to solve the problem I'm stuck on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651293/using-datatestmethod-datarow-with-vb-net-only-one-datarow-gets-exec). I'm using MSTest to select one of a set of arrays of bytes to pass to a function under test.
I'm trying this approach as I haven't been able to get MSTest working directly passing an array of bytes to the test function.

I want to set up a `Private ReadOnly` jagged array of arrays of Bytes (TestMsgs) as part of my test class to allow the test subroutine to access elements one by one. Currently I'm getting error BC30201 "Expression Expected" as below. Something is missing in my initialisation, but I can't find any example on how to initialise this jagged array.

```
    Public Class DecoderTests
        Private ReadOnly TestMsgs As Byte()() = New Byte(2)() {
            New Byte() {&HA1, &HB2, &HC3}, 'Test array should Pass
            New Byte() {&HA2, &HB3},       'Test array should Fail
            }                    <========= Error BC30201 Here
        Private DecoderInstance
```

Here is the full code of my test (Simplified to debug the original issue)

Test Class

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Namespace TestDecoder.Tests
    <TestClass>
    Public Class DecoderTests
        Private ReadOnly TestMsgs As Byte()() = New Byte(2)() {
            New Byte() {&HA1, &HB2, &HC3}, 'Test array should Pass
            New Byte() {&HA2, &HB3},       'Test array should Fail
            }
        Private DecoderInstance
        <DataTestMethod>
        <DataRow(0)>
        <DataRow(1)>
        Public Sub ParseTestData(message_number)
            Dim result As Boolean
            DecoderInstance = New Decoder()
            result = DecoderInstance.parse(TestMsgs(message_number)(0))
            Assert.IsTrue(result, "Failed the dummy test")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Simplified Class under test:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic



Public Class Decoder
    Function parse(rxchar As Byte) As Boolean
        Return rxchar = &H41
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is the issue or the only issue but you have an erroneous comma after the second inner array.

Comment: Thanks. You got it (in combination with the length was wrong). Your solution below is much simpler.

Comment: Note that C# allows the extra comma.

Comment: As does C - which is kind-of my native language right now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this code and there were no errors:

```vb
Private ReadOnly TestMsgs As Byte()() = {
                                            New Byte() {&HA1, &HB2, &HC3},
                                            New Byte() {&HA2, &HB3}
                                        }
```

I think the issue with your original code was that you were specifying the size of the array explicitly and also initialising it, therefore specifying the size of the array implicitly. I just tested this code and it worked too:

```vb
Private ReadOnly TestMsgs As Byte()() = New Byte()() {
                                                         New Byte() {&HA1, &HB2, &HC3},
                                                         New Byte() {&HA2, &HB3}
                                                     }
```

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney . This got me to take another look, and the difference was that I had an extra comma after the second array. (and the 'size' of the main array was wrong!) .